# Getting the onclick method of a dynamically generated DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm dynamically adding images with an onclick method to my page as follows:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = "image.png";
image.onclick = function(){
    doSomething();
}

parent.appendChild(image);
```

This all works fine. However, I think want to save (via a PHP script) the generated HTML, **with the onclick method**. I've tried using parent.innerHTML, but whilst that returns the image the onclick isn't there.

I'm getting:

```
...<img src="image.png" />...
```

When what I want is something along the lines of:

```
...<img src="image.png" onclick="doSomething()" />...
```

Can someone help me work out how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that isn't possible. What if the function was returned from a closure? Where would the enclosed variables come from if it was stringified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not really possible. A living function instance is not serializable with all its scope environments and other internal or public properties. You could only get its code, doing something like

```
image.setAttribute(
  "onclick",
  image.onclick.toString().replace(/^function\s*([^)]*)\s*\{?|\}$|\n/g, "")
);
return image.outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing script outside an element attribute either in a `<script>` tag or in an external file it will never be replicated in the HTML. What you're looking for is not possible as far as I know.

If you write the onclick function directly in to the HTML and then extract it then that would work.

Comment: How would I write the onclick function directly into the HTML from Javascript?

Comment: See @Bergi's answer - thats probably the best way to hack it. Not really an advisable thing to do though...